# Unique Property of Strings to build an efficient Hash Table

Tags: c++, string, hash, hash-function

What is the unique property of strings in C++? Why can they be compared by relational operators (e.g. when trying to sort an array of strings alphabetically)? I am trying to capitalize on this "property" in order to build a fine hashing function for a table with no collisions for every possible string. Also, what data structure would work for this? I'm thinking a vector because I will have to go through a document without knowing how many unique words are in it, and I want to go through the document just once.

Comment: The relational operators are usually overloads that contains some complex function like c's `strcmp`. So it's not that simple in fact.

Comment: Comparing strings is like comparing base-256 numbers digit by digit.

Answer (score 0):

C++ standard strings are essentially vectors of characters. Comparing strings thus means to compare them character by character from the beginning.
I'm not sure what you mean by 'unique property', but for your usecase any hashing algorithm should do.
If I understand your usecase correctly, you might want to use a std::set< YourHashType > or std::map. That way you wouldn't have to take care of finding out whether a word was already added or not.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple algorithm that calculates the hash key for a null-terminated C-style string is the following:

```
UINT HashKey(const char* key) const
{
    UINT nHash = 0;
    while (*key)
        nHash = (nHash<<5) + nHash + *key++;
    return nHash;
}
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at [P0029R0](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0029r0.html) for a composable approach capable of creating good (although possibly not cryptograpic) hash values.

Comment: I agree that it is a complex topic and there are many aspects but I was just trying to provide a basic idea of how to implement a hash calculating algorithm for a string.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to capitalize on this "property" in order to build a fine hashing function for a table with no collisions for every possible string.

As an example of the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), you can't have a collision free hash function.  Strings sort uniquely when you compare them lexically (e.g. letter by letter) using a function like [`std::strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp), but that only gives you a unique ordering using comparison and not an intrinsic unique property of a string.

If you have a finite set of keys, you can design a collision free hash function though, which is referred to as [perfect hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function).